# How can I save the file received in a multipart/form-data POST request using go's net/http or similar alternative?

Tags: go, multipartform-data

For context, I am trying to create a custom image uploader for the program ShareX (https://getsharex.com/docs/custom-uploader). I have tried many search terms, however I can't find any solutions to this question.

Here's my current code (located in file main.go):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func handleUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(16384)
    f, fi, _ := r.FormFile("file_image")
    _ = f
    fmt.Println(fi.Filename, fi.Size)

}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/upload", handleUpload)
    fmt.Println("Starting listener on port 8085")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8085", mux)
}
```

My goal here is to save the file (image) data received from the request to a local file, however I am unable to do that since writing to a file requires type `[]byte` and `f` is of type `multipart.File`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a example of how you can deal with form data.

The main idea here is to use the io pkg https://golang.org/pkg/io/

`r.FormFile` returns an interface of type `File`. `File` implements `Reader` and `Writer` method. So we can copy the content from one file and write that to an empty file.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "POST":
        r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20) //10 MB
        file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file_image")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error retrieving file", err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        defer file.Close()
        dst, err := os.Create(handler.Filename)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("error creating file", err)
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        defer dst.Close()
        if _, err := io.Copy(dst, file); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "uploaded file")
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/upload", uploadHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8085", nil)
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help! One question though, how exactly does `10 << 20` work?

Comment: its a left shift. think of 10 moved left 20 times so it ends up being 10 then 20 zeroes.